# Creating a flexible ruby DSL with lambdas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to create a flexible dsl. I already have the DSL module, say `module DSL`. The DSL user can create spin-offs of this as a class. The main point of the DSL is to allow the user to create `Feature` object with a custom render method. There was a lot of ugly and non-DRY code backing the `Feature`, hence the abstraction, but the user needs a lot of control on how that feature renders, and my meta-programming is not up to the task. Let me show you how it's set up.

The DSL looks something like this:

```
module DSL
  module ClassMethods
      attr_accessor :features
      def column(name, *args)
        arguments = args.pop || {}
        self.features = [] if self.features.nil?
        self.features << Feature.new(name, arguments)
      end
    end
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end
  end
end
```

An implementation of it would look something like this:

```
class DSLSpinOff
  include DSL

  feature :one
  feature :two, render_with: :predefined_render
  feature :three, render_with: :user_defined_render
  feature :four, render_with: lambda {
    puts "Go nuts, user!"
    puts "Do as you please!"
  }

  def user_defined_render
    #...
  end
end
```

And finally, the feature class itself lies within the DSL, like so:

```
module DSL
  #...
private
  class Feature
    attr_accessor :name, :render_with
    def initialize(name, *args)
      self.name = name
      attributes = args.pop || {}
      # somehow delegate attributes[:render_with] to the render function, handling defaults, lamdbas, function string names, etc
      self.render_with = attributes.fetch(:render_with, :default_render)
    end

  private
    def default_render
      #...
    end

    def predefined_render
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic I was looking for: `define_singleton_method`.

```
module DSL
  #...
private
  class Feature
    attr_accessor :name
    def initialize(name, args)
      #...
      define_singleton_method :render do
        if self.render_with.kind_of? Symbol
          content = self.send(self.render_with)
        else
          content = self.render_with.call
        end
        content.present? ? content.to_s.html_safe : '&ndash;'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now within the DSL I can iterate over all features and render them. It'll send itself `:default_render`, or some other `:predefined_render`, or use the block provided instead. However, this does not let users define methods on within the `DSLSpinOff` and pass them in,  since those methods would get delegated to the `DSLSpinOff` class instead of the `DSLSpinOff::Column` class.

I suspect they would have to do something like:

```
feature :three, render_with: self.method(:user_defined_render)
def user_defined_render
  #...
end
```

### Edit:

I found a clean way to allow use of a default method, user-defined lambdas, pre-defined methods, and user-defined methods:

```
module DSL
  #...
  class Feature
    attr_accessor :name, render_with
    def initialize(name, *args)
      self.name = name
      self.render_with = args.has_key?(:render_with) ? args[:render_with] : :default_render
      define_singleton_method :render do |object|
        render_method = self.render_with.is_a?(Proc) ? renderer : method(renderer) 
        render_method.call
      end
    end

  private
    def default_render
      #...
    end

    def predefined_render
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

This will grab lambdas or procs if the user passes those in, otherwise, it'll use the `method` method to return a reference to the method defined on the`Feature`. The `call` method works on all three.

To support user-defined render methods, just have the open the class in an initializer to make it findable by the `method` method:

```
#initializers/custom_dsl_renders.rb
class DSL::Feature
  def user_defined_render
    #...
  end
end
```

Comment: Give yourself the selected answer when SO will allow it.